# UI solution for C++ / Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, user-interface

New programmer question! My goal is code up some simple UI's to help visualize some C++ assignments I have. Is there a native solution to use in C++ in Visual Studio 2012?

Looking for something like:

```
#using <Some_UI_Solution>

class Window(....) : .....
{
    gridLayout(....

    show();
};
```

I've looked around a bit, and am overwhelmed with all the info out there. Thanks for any help! Feel free to edit question as needed.

Comment: GUI's from C++ are often a pain to use. I would suggest looking into the Qt Library. There are other platform specific things you can do too.

Comment: Keep in mind C++ is quite low level, your going to have to write a few hundred lines of code for a native C++ solution or use a gui library that wraps it.

Comment: What is the native solution, though? I think that's what I'm after. @JesseGood

Comment: @patrick: The native solution would be the winapi, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381399%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/07/25/10189090.aspx) for tutorials.

Comment: @JesseGood: You have things backwards. The Win32 API is what's low level. Using it directly from other languages works out just as badly (or worse) as it does from C++. The primary difference is that nobody would generally consider using it directly from most other languages.

Comment: Indeed - the *technical* answer to your question is that from C++, without a GUI library, you must use the Windows SDK.  (This is what all GUI libraries internally use, themselves.)  However, I think it's safe to say that even for most commercial applications - and **especially** for quick-and-dirty applications - the Windows SDK is far too tedious (except for the occasional call).  Instead, a library is used - Qt (http://qt-project.org) being perhaps the most important one in C++.  Even here, you must be rather familiar WITH Qt in order to be able to "whip something off" in it.

Comment: Note: If you are familiar with MFC (Microsoft Foundation Classes), which comes included with Visual Studio, then it *IS* easy to whip off quick-and-dirty UI's in C++ on Windows (but it's not cross-platform).  I do this pretty frequently.  But MFC is a pretty big hassle to learn and, I think, the large majority of C++ programmers don't know it at all.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: Also, I don't think MFC is included in the entry-level Visual Studio Express version.

Comment: Thanks for all the info, everyone! This is all very helpful!